# Does Angular2 have an equivalent of $document

Tags: angular

I've started looking into Angular2 and have a basic up with 3 nested componenets working. However I cannot work out how to add a keypress handler to the document.

If not, how would I listen for a keypress on the document and react to it?
To be clear I need to respond to a kepyress on the document itself, NOT an input.

In Angular 1 I would create a directive and use $document; something like this:

```
 $document.on("keydown", function(event) {

      // if keycode...
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();

      scope.$apply(function() {            
        // update scope...          
      });
```

But I have yet to find an Angular2 solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@Component({
  host: {
    '(document:keyup)': '_keyup($event)',
    '(document:keydown)': '_keydown($event)',
  },
})
export class Component {
  private _keydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    let prevent = [13, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40]
      .find(no => no === event.keyCode);
    if (prevent) event.preventDefault();
  }
  private _keyup(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) this.close();
    else if (event.keyCode === 13) ...;
    else if (event.keyCode === 37) ...;
    else if (event.keyCode === 38) ...;
    else if (event.keyCode === 39) ...;
    else if (event.keyCode === 40) ...;

    // else console.log(event.keyCode);
  }
}
```

BTW, Angular team had some interesting [ideas about keyboard events](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/909031e6887175b380492119df3b694d164c66eb/modules/angular2/test/platform/dom/events/key_events_spec.ts), not sure what's the status of this at the moment. It's even possible [it's working](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/523), didn't try myself :)

Comment: I haven't seen the `document:keyup` syntax before.  Do you have any references for that so I can learn more?

Comment: @MarkRajcok Not sure where I found it for the first time.. I know I saw `<input #box (keyup.enter)="values=box.value">` at official [Developer Guides](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html) - look for **Key event filtering**... I'll try to find where I got `document:_event_` syntax. Works with `window:click` too, for example.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I was looking for "click outside" some time ago, and I found the code for [Angular2 Modal](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/blob/master/src/angular2-modal/components/bootstrapModalContainer.ts). After that I looked through source code for [key_events](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/platform/dom/events/key_events.ts) and with some experimenting I got to this syntax...

Comment: So almost 2 months later I found it... Buried deep in the API doc for DirectiveMetadata, [under the host property](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DirectiveMetadata-class.html#host) we find these words: "To listen to global events, a target must be added to the event name. The target can be `window`, `document` or `body`."

Comment: The link to the host property changed: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DirectiveMetadata-class.html#!#host-listeners (I wish there was a way to edit comments).