# How can I close a dropdown on click outside?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, angular, rxjs

I would like to close my login menu dropdown when the user click anywhere outside of that dropdown, and I'd like to do that with Angular2 and with the Angular2 "approach"...

I have implemented a solution, but I really do not feel confident with it. I think there must be an easiest way to achieve the same result, so if you have any ideas ... let's discuss :) !

Here is my implementation:

## The dropdown component:

This is the component for my dropdown:

- Every time this component it set to visible, (For example: when the user click on a button to display it) it subscribe to a "global" rxjs subject *userMenu* stored within the *SubjectsService*.
- And every time it is hidden, it unsubscribe to this subject.
- Every click anywhere **within** the template of this component trigger the *onClick()* method, which just stop event bubbling to the top (and the application component)

Here is the code

```
export class UserMenuComponent {

    _isVisible: boolean = false;
    _subscriptions: Subscription<any> = null;

    constructor(public subjects: SubjectsService) {
    }

    onClick(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }

    set isVisible(v) {
        if( v ){
            setTimeout( () => {
this._subscriptions =  this.subjects.userMenu.subscribe((e) => {
                       this.isVisible = false;
                       })
            }, 0);
        } else {
            this._subscriptions.unsubscribe();
        }
        this._isVisible = v;
    }

    get isVisible() {
        return this._isVisible;
    }
}
```

## The application component:

On the other hand, there is the application component (which is a parent of the dropdown component):

- This component catch every click event and emit on the same rxjs Subject (*userMenu*)

Here is the code:

```
export class AppComponent {

    constructor( public subjects: SubjectsService) {
        document.addEventListener('click', () => this.onClick());
    }
    onClick( ) {
        this.subjects.userMenu.next({});
    }
}
```

## What bother me:

1. I do not feel really comfortable with the idea of having a global Subject that act as the connector between those components.
2. The **setTimeout**: This is needed because here is what happen otherwise if the user click on the button that show the dropdown:

   - The user click on the button (which is not a part of the dropdown component) to show the dropdown.
   - The dropdown is displayed and **it immediately subscribe to the userMenu subject**.
   - The click event bubble up to the app component and gets caught
   - The application component emit an event on the **userMenu** subject
   - The dropdown component catch this action on **userMenu** and hide the dropdown.
   - At the end the dropdown is never displayed.

This set timeout delay the subscription to the end of the current JavaScript code turn which solve the problem, but in a very in elegant way in my opinion.

If you know cleaner, better, smarter, faster or stronger solutions, please let me know :) !

Comment: These answers may give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35028820/215945, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024495#35024651

Answer (score 268, accepted):

You can use `(document:click)` event:

```
@Component({
  host: {
    '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
  },
})
class SomeComponent() {
  constructor(private _eref: ElementRef) { }

  onClick(event) {
   if (!this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) // or some similar check
     doSomething();
  }
}
```

Another approach is to create custom event as a directive. Check out these posts by Ben Nadel:

- [tracking-click-events-outside-the-current-component](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3009-tracking-click-events-outside-the-current-component-in-angular-2-beta-1.htm)
- [selectors-and-outputs-can-have-the-same-name](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3024-selectors-and-outputs-can-have-the-same-name-in-angular-2-beta-6.htm)
- [DirectiveMetadata](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive)
- [Host Binding](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding)

Comment: Thanks ! Where did you get the documentation for the host attribute of the ComponentMetadata annotation ?
The angular2 documentation is empty for that attribute.

Comment: ^^^ That info here link is 404.

Comment: @danludwig I've updated the answer with working link. You can always do a search yoursefl in docs (:

Comment: @Sasxa thank you, and agreed. I figured if there was a non-deprecated API doc, it would have showed up in the search that led me here.

Comment: If event.target is an element that was added dynamically through something like an [innerHTML] binding then the elementRef's nativeElement will not contain it.

Comment: This is cool. But in ngOnDestroy I need to destroy the event if I use this in more than one component to avoid conflicts? Thank you

Comment: This doesn't work for me, once the component is added to the view, it receives the click event (I'd have imagined it shouldn't since it wasn't in the view when the click happened), and because the target is not contained in the view, it closes itself. I don't understand why the component would get the click event.

Stopping the propagation on the click fixes this though.

Comment: The only downside to this technique is that now you have a click event listener in your application that fires every time you click.

Comment: According to the official Angular 2 style guide, you should use `@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])` instead of `host` property on the `Component` decorator.

Comment: I've run into a problem when about 1000 elements ended up listening to `document:click` - even if I leave the body of `onClick` empty, just having it attached to the event causes the page to freeze for a few seconds whenever the user clicks absolutely anything. I guess I'll need to figure out something different.

Comment: Mind that this solution will trigger ApplicationRef.tick on each click anywhere on document. I suggest to run this code outside angular zone, and enter zone only if the condition truthy

Comment: or you could just use rxjs for it, like `Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click').subscribe(event => {your code here})`, so you can always subscribe only when you need to listen for example you opened dropdown, and when you close it you unsubscribe

Comment: whats is _eref in this case? I am getting error on this

Comment: I removed that _eref thing. Now issue is this other click handlers are not working. Only current click event is called

Comment: Unresolved variable or type $event

Answer (score 58):

### ELEGANT METHOD

I found this `clickOut` directive:
https://github.com/chliebel/angular2-click-outside. I check it and it works well (i only copy `clickOutside.directive.ts` to my project). U can use it in this way:

```
<div (clickOutside)="close($event)"></div>
```

Where `close` is your function which will be call when user click outside div. It is very elegant way to handle problem described in question.

If you use above directive to close popUp window, remember first to add `event.stopPropagation()` to button click event handler which open popUp.

#### BONUS:

Below i copy oryginal directive code from file `clickOutside.directive.ts` (in case if link will stop working in future) - the author is [Christian Liebel](https://github.com/chliebel) :

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
    
@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Output()
    public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }

        const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vega My recomendation would be to use the Directive in an element with *ngIf, in the case of dropdowns, this can be something like `<div class="wrap" *ngIf="isOpened" (clickOutside)="...// this should set this.isOpen=false"`

Answer (score 21):

I've done it this way.

Added an event listener on document `click` and in that handler checked if my `container` contains `event.target`, if not - hide the dropdown.

It would look like this.

```
@Component({})
class SomeComponent {
    @ViewChild('container') container;
    @ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown;

    constructor() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.offClickHandler.bind(this)); // bind on doc
    }

    offClickHandler(event:any) {
        if (!this.container.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) { // check click origin
            this.dropdown.nativeElement.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Is the.bind(this) necessary?

Comment: @Brian It may or may not be necessary, but definitely wouldn't be if he wrapped the `this.offClickHandler` in an arrow function.

Answer (score 17):

I think Sasxa accepted answer works for most people. However, I had a situation, where the content of the Element, that should listen to off-click events, changed dynamically. So the Elements nativeElement did not contain the event.target, when it was created dynamically.
I could solve this with the following directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myOffClick]'
})
export class MyOffClickDirective {

  @Output() offClick = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.path'])
  public onGlobalClick(targetElementPath: Array<any>) {
    let elementRefInPath = targetElementPath.find(e => e === this._elementRef.nativeElement);
    if (!elementRefInPath) {
      this.offClick.emit(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of checking if elementRef contains event.target, I check if elementRef is in the path (DOM path to target) of the event. That way it is possible to handle dynamically created Elements.

Comment: Thanks - this works better when child components are present

Comment: This was much helpful for me. not sure why outside the component click was not getting detected with other answers.

Comment: how to use this.

Answer (score 13):

### If you're doing this on iOS, use the `touchstart` event as well:

As of Angular 4, the `HostListener` decorate is the preferred way to do this

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
...
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implement OnInit {

  constructor(private eRef: ElementRef){}

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('document:touchstart', ['$event'])
  handleOutsideClick(event) {
    // Some kind of logic to exclude clicks in Component.
    // This example is borrowed Kamil's answer
    if (!this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target) {
      doSomethingCool();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

We've been working on a similar issue at work today, trying to figure out how to make a dropdown div disappear when it is clicked off of. Ours is slightly different than the initial poster's question because we didn't want to click away from a different *component* or *directive*, but merely outside of the particular div.

We ended up solving it by using the (window:mouseup) event handler.

Steps:
1.) We gave the entire dropdown menu div a unique class name.
2.) On the inner dropdown menu itself (the only portion that we wanted clicks to NOT close the menu), we added a (window:mouseup) event handler and passed in the $event. 
NOTE: It could not be done with a typical "click" handler because this conflicted with the parent click handler.
3.) In our controller, we created the method that we wanted to be called on the click out event, and we use the event.closest ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)) to find out if the clicked spot is within our targeted-class div.

```js
 autoCloseForDropdownCars(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        if (!target.closest(".DropdownCars")) { 
            // do whatever you want here
        }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="DropdownCars">
   <span (click)="toggleDropdown(dropdownTypes.Cars)" class="searchBarPlaceholder">Cars</span>
   <div class="criteriaDropdown" (window:mouseup)="autoCloseForDropdownCars($event)" *ngIf="isDropdownShown(dropdownTypes.Cars)">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "window:mouseup" should be used within the host decorator.

Comment: @Shivam-- I'm not sure what you mean by "should be used within the host decorator." Could you possibly explain further? Thanks!

Comment: I mean instead of using "window" object directly, you should use "host" property of component decorator / "HostListener" decorator of component. That is standard practice while working with "window" or "document" object in angular 2.

Comment: Just keep an eye for browser compatibility, `.closest()` is not supported on IE/Edge as of today ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=element-closest))

Answer (score 8):

You can use `mouseleave` in your view like this

Test with angular 8 and work perfectly

```
<ul (mouseleave)="closeDropdown()"> </ul>
```

Comment: This will close the container when the mouse leaves, but thank you for sharing anyway as I was unaware of its existence.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't make any workaround. I've just attached document:click on my toggle function as follow :

```
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appDropDown]'
    })
    export class DropdownDirective implements OnInit {

      @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen: boolean;

      constructor(private elemRef: ElementRef) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.isOpen = false;
      }

      @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
      @HostListener('document:touchstart', ['$event'])
      toggle(event) {
        if (this.elemRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
          this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
        } else {
          this.isOpen = false;
      }
    }
```

So, when I am outside my directive, I close the dropdown.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a sibling element to the dropdown that covers the entire screen that would be invisible and be there just for capturing click events. Then you could detect clicks on that element and close the dropdown when it is clicked. Lets say that element is of class silkscreen, here is some style for it:

```
.silkscreen {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The z-index needs to be high enough to position it above everything but your dropdown. In this case my dropdown would b z-index 2.

The other answers worked in some cases for me, except sometimes my dropdown closed when I interacted with elements within it and I didn't want that. I had dynamically added elements who were not contained in my component, according to the event target, like I expected. Rather than sorting that mess out I figured I'd just try it the silkscreen way.

Answer (score 4):

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-dropdown',
    template: `
        <div class="custom-dropdown-container">
            Dropdown code here
        </div>
    `
})
export class CustomDropdownComponent {
    thisElementClicked: boolean = false;

    constructor() { }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onLocalClick(event: Event) {
        this.thisElementClicked = true;
    }

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event: Event) {
        if (!this.thisElementClicked) {
            //click was outside the element, do stuff
        }
        this.thisElementClicked = false;
    }
}
```

DOWNSIDES:
- Two click event listeners for every one of these components on page. Don't use this on components that are on the page hundreds of times.

Comment: No, I've only used it on the desktop browser.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to complement @Tony answer, since the event is not being removed after the click outside the component. Complete receipt:

- Mark your main element with #container

  ```
  @ViewChild('container') container;

  _dropstatus: boolean = false;
  get dropstatus() { return this._dropstatus; }
  set dropstatus(b: boolean) 
  {
      if (b) { document.addEventListener('click', this.offclickevent);}
      else { document.removeEventListener('click', this.offclickevent);}
      this._dropstatus = b;
  }
  offclickevent: any = ((evt:any) => { if (!this.container.nativeElement.contains(evt.target)) this.dropstatus= false; }).bind(this);
  ```
- On the clickable element, use:

  ```
  (click)="dropstatus=true"
  ```

Now you can control your dropdown state with the dropstatus variable, and apply proper classes with [ngClass]...

Answer (score 3):

You can write directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOut]'
})
export class ClickOutDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() clickOut: boolean;

  @Output() clickOutEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event']) onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {

       if (this.clickOut && 
         !event.path.includes(this._element.nativeElement))
       {
           this.clickOutEvent.emit();
       }
  } 


}
```

In your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1 *ngIf="isVisible" 
      [clickOut]="true" 
      (clickOutEvent)="onToggle()"
    >{{title}}</h1>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  isVisible = false;

  onToggle() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
  }
}
```

This directive emit event when html element is containing in DOM and when [clickOut] input property is 'true'.
It listen mousedown event to handle event before element will be removed from DOM.

And one note:
firefox doesn't contain property 'path' on event you can use function to create path:

```
const getEventPath = (event: Event): HTMLElement[] => {
  if (event['path']) {
    return event['path'];
  }
  if (event['composedPath']) {
    return event['composedPath']();
  }
  const path = [];
  let node = <HTMLElement>event.target;
  do {
    path.push(node);
  } while (node = node.parentElement);
  return path;
};
```

So you should change event handler on the directive:
  event.path should be replaced getEventPath(event)

This module can help. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-clickout
It contains the same logic but also handle esc event on source html element.

Answer (score 3):

You should check if you click on the modal overlay instead, a lot easier.

Your template:

```
<div #modalOverlay (click)="clickOutside($event)" class="modal fade show" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
        <div class="modal-dialog" [ngClass]='size' role="document">
            <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
                <div class="close-modal" (click)="closeModal()"> <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <ng-content></ng-content>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the method:

```
    @ViewChild('modalOverlay') modalOverlay: ElementRef;
    
    // ... your constructor and other methods
    
    clickOutside(event: Event) {
        const target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        console.log('click', target);
        console.log("outside???", this.modalOverlay.nativeElement == event.target)
        // const isClickOutside = !this.modalBody.nativeElement.contains(event.target);
        // console.log("click outside ?", isClickOutside);
        if ("isClickOutside") {
          // this.closeModal();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer has a problem, if you have a clicakble component in your popover, the element will no longer on the `contain` method and will close, based on @JuHarm89 i created my own:

```
export class PopOverComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 private parentNode: any;

  constructor(
    private _element: ElementRef
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.parentNode = this._element.nativeElement.parentNode;
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.path'])
  onClickOutside($event: Array<any>) {
    const elementRefInPath = $event.find(node => node === this.parentNode);
    if (!elementRefInPath) {
      this.closeEventEmmit.emit();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

A better version for @Tony great solution:

```
@Component({})
class SomeComponent {
    @ViewChild('container') container;
    @ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown;

    constructor() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.offClickHandler.bind(this)); // bind on doc
    }

    offClickHandler(event:any) {
        if (!this.container.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) { // check click origin

            this.dropdown.nativeElement.closest(".ourDropdown.open").classList.remove("open");

        }
    }
}
```

In a css file: //NOT needed if you use bootstrap drop-down.

```
.ourDropdown{
   display: none;
}
.ourDropdown.open{
   display: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't think there were enough answers so I want to pitch in. Here's what I did

component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-issue',
    templateUrl: './issue.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./issue.component.sass'],
})
export class IssueComponent {
    @Input() issue: IIssue;
    @ViewChild('issueRef') issueRef;
    
    public dropdownHidden = true;
    
    constructor(private ref: ElementRef) {}

    public toggleDropdown($event) {
        this.dropdownHidden = !this.dropdownHidden;
    }
    
    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    public hideDropdown(event: any) {
        if (!this.dropdownHidden && !this.issueRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
            this.dropdownHidden = true;
        }
    }
}
```

component.html

```
<div #issueRef (click)="toggleDropdown()">
    <div class="card card-body">
        <p class="card-text truncate">{{ issue.fields.summary }}</p>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <img
                *ngIf="issue.fields.assignee; else unassigned"
                class="rounded"
                [src]="issue.fields.assignee.avatarUrls['32x32']"
                [alt]="issue.fields.assignee.displayName"
            />
            <ng-template #unassigned>
                <img
                    class="rounded"
                    src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/person-male--v2.png"
                    alt="Unassigned"
                />
            </ng-template>
            <img
                *ngIf="issue.fields.priority"
                class="rounded mt-auto priority"
                [src]="issue.fields.priority.iconUrl"
                [alt]="issue.fields.priority.name"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!dropdownHidden" class="list-group context-menu">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" aria-current="true">
            The current link item
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">A second link item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">A third link item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">A fourth link item</a>
        <a
            href="#"
            class="list-group-item list-group-item-action disabled"
            tabindex="-1"
            aria-disabled="true"
            >A disabled link item</a
        >
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap, you can do it directly with bootstrap way via  dropdowns (Bootstrap component).

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
            Toggle Drop Down. <span class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now it's OK to put `(click)="clickButton()"` stuff on the button.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Answer (score 1):

I also did a little workaround of my own.

I created a ***(dropdownOpen)*** event which I listen to at my ng-select element component and call a function which will close all the other SelectComponent's opened apart from the currently opened SelectComponent.

I modified one  function inside the ***select.ts*** file like below to emit the event:

```
private open():void {
    this.options = this.itemObjects
        .filter((option:SelectItem) => (this.multiple === false ||
        this.multiple === true && !this.active.find((o:SelectItem) => option.text === o.text)));

    if (this.options.length > 0) {
        this.behavior.first();
    }
    this.optionsOpened = true;
    this.dropdownOpened.emit(true);
}
```

In the HTML I added an event listener for *(dropdownOpened)*:

```
<ng-select #elem (dropdownOpened)="closeOtherElems(elem)"
    [multiple]="true"
    [items]="items"
    [disabled]="disabled"
    [isInputAllowed]="true"
    (data)="refreshValue($event)"
    (selected)="selected($event)"
    (removed)="removed($event)"
    placeholder="No city selected"></ng-select>
```

This is my calling function on event trigger inside the component having ng2-select tag:

```
@ViewChildren(SelectComponent) selectElem :QueryList<SelectComponent>;

public closeOtherElems(element){
    let a = this.selectElem.filter(function(el){
                return (el != element)
            });

    a.forEach(function(e:SelectComponent){
        e.closeDropdown();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** For those wanting to use web workers and you need to avoid using document and nativeElement this will work.

I answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571144

**Copy/Paste from the above link:**

I had the same issue when I was making a drop-down menu and a confirmation dialog I wanted to dismiss them when clicking outside.

My final implementation works perfectly but requires some css3 animations and styling.

**NOTE**: i have not tested the below code, there may be some syntax problems that need to be ironed out, also the obvious adjustments for your own project!

**What i did:**

I made a separate fixed div with height 100%, width 100% and transform:scale(0), this is essentially the background, you can style it with background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.466); to make obvious the menu is open and the background is click-to-close.
The menu gets a z-index higher than everything else, then the background div gets a z-index lower than the menu but also higher than everything else. Then the background has a click event that close the drop-down.

Here it is with your html code.

```
<div class="dropdownbackground" [ngClass]="{showbackground: qtydropdownOpened}" (click)="qtydropdownOpened = !qtydropdownOpened"><div>
<div class="zindex" [class.open]="qtydropdownOpened">
  <button (click)="qtydropdownOpened = !qtydropdownOpened" type="button" 
         data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" [attr.aria-expanded]="qtydropdownOpened ? 'true': 'false' ">
   {{selectedqty}}<span class="caret margin-left-1x "></span>
 </button>
  <div class="dropdown-wrp dropdown-menu">
  <ul class="default-dropdown">
      <li *ngFor="let quantity of quantities">
       <a (click)="qtydropdownOpened = !qtydropdownOpened;setQuantity(quantity)">{{quantity  }}</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the css3 which needs some simple animations.

```
/* make sure the menu/drop-down is in front of the background */
.zindex{
    z-index: 3;
}

/* make background fill the whole page but sit behind the drop-down, then
scale it to 0 so its essentially gone from the page */
.dropdownbackground{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.466);
}

/* this is the class we add in the template when the drop down is opened
it has the animation rules set these how you like */
.showbackground{
    animation: showBackGround 0.4s 1 forwards; 

}

/* this animates the background to fill the page
if you don't want any thing visual you could use a transition instead */
@keyframes showBackGround {
    1%{
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

If you aren't after anything visual you can just use a transition like this

```
.dropdownbackground{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    transition all 0.1s;
}

.dropdownbackground.showbackground{
     transform: scale(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**THE MOST ELEGANT METHOD :D**

There is one easiest way to do that, no need any directives for that.

"element-that-toggle-your-dropdown" should be button tag. Use any method in (blur) attribute. That's all.

```
<button class="element-that-toggle-your-dropdown"
               (blur)="isDropdownOpen = false"
               (click)="isDropdownOpen = !isDropdownOpen">
</button>
```

Comment: This wont work if you want to keep the dropdown open on click, for example a user might miss click a button

Answer (score 1):

I came across to another solution, inspired by examples with focus/blur event.

So, if you want to achieve the same functionality without attaching global document listener, you may consider as a valid the following example. It works also in Safari and Firefox on OSx, despite they have other handling of button focus event:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus

Working example on stackbiz with angular 8: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sv4tbi?file=src%2Ftoggle-dropdown%2Ftoggle-dropdown.directive.ts

HTML markup:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown button</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The directive will look like this:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, ElementRef, OnDestroy, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '.dropdown'
})
export class ToggleDropdownDirective {

  @HostBinding('class.show')
  public isOpen: boolean;

  private buttonMousedown: () => void;
  private buttonBlur: () => void;
  private navMousedown: () => void;
  private navClick: () => void;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const el = this.element.nativeElement;
    const btnElem = el.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle');
    const menuElem = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');

    this.buttonMousedown = this.renderer.listen(btnElem, 'mousedown', (evt) => {
      console.log('MOUSEDOWN BTN');
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
      evt.preventDefault(); // prevents loose of focus (default behaviour) on some browsers
    });

    this.buttonMousedown = this.renderer.listen(btnElem, 'click', () => {
      console.log('CLICK BTN');
      // firefox OSx, Safari, Ie OSx, Mobile browsers.
      // Whether clicking on a <button> causes it to become focused varies by browser and OS.
      btnElem.focus();
    });

    // only for debug
    this.buttonMousedown = this.renderer.listen(btnElem, 'focus', () => {
      console.log('FOCUS BTN');
    });

    this.buttonBlur = this.renderer.listen(btnElem, 'blur', () => {
      console.log('BLUR BTN');
      this.isOpen = false;
    });

    this.navMousedown = this.renderer.listen(menuElem, 'mousedown', (evt) => {
      console.log('MOUSEDOWN MENU');
      evt.preventDefault(); // prevents nav element to get focus and button blur event to fire too early
    });
    this.navClick = this.renderer.listen(menuElem, 'click', () => {
      console.log('CLICK MENU');
      this.isOpen = false;
      btnElem.blur();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.buttonMousedown();
    this.buttonBlur();
    this.navMousedown();
    this.navClick();
  }
}
```

Comment: ElementRef's use is highly discouraged by Angular team due to the security reason, and loose coupling design of any angular app.

Comment: Hi Kumar, please, note that in my solution i use a directive, and using elementRef in a directive it is quite common and encouraged by angular team (https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives). I assume that using elementRef in a component it is not a good idea and may be discouraged, but for a directive it is quite normal.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to post my own solution based on my use case. I have a href with a (click) event in Angular 11. This toggles a menu component in the main app.ts on off/

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="menu-link" (click)="toggleMenu();" ><img id="menu-image" src="img/icons/menu-white.png" ></a></li>
```

The menu component (e.g. div) is visible (*ngIf) based on a boolean named "isMenuVisible". And of course it can be a dropdown or any component.

In the app.ts I have this simple function

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
onClick(event: Event) {

    const elementId = (event.target as Element).id;
    if (elementId.includes("menu")) {
        return;
    }

    this.isMenuVisble = false;

}
```

This means that clicking anywhere outside the "named" context closes/hides the "named" component.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Angular Bootstrap DropDowns button sample with close outside of component.

without use `bootstrap.js`

```
// .html
<div class="mx-3 dropdown" [class.show]="isTestButton">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle"
          (click)="isTestButton = !isTestButton">
    <span>Month</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" [class.show]="isTestButton">
    <button class="btn dropdown-item">Month</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown-item">Week</button>
  </div>
</div>

// .ts
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-test",
  templateUrl: "./test.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./test.component.scss"]
})
export class TestComponent {

  isTestButton = false;

  constructor(private eleRef: ElementRef) {
  }


  @HostListener("document:click", ["$event"])
  docEvent($e: MouseEvent) {
    if (!this.isTestButton) {
      return;
    }
    const paths: Array<HTMLElement> = $e["path"];
    if (!paths.some(p => p === this.eleRef.nativeElement)) {
      this.isTestButton = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Super complicated. I read them but not possible to reproduce them with my code.
I have this code for a dropdown menu in java.

```
document.addEventListener("mouseover", e => { 
  const isDropdownButton = e.target.matches("[data-dropdown-button]")
  if (!isDropdownButton && e.closest('[data-dropdown]') != null) return
  
  let currentDropDown
  if (isDropdownButton) {
    currentDropdown = e.target.closest('[data-dropdown]')
    currentDropdown.classList.toggle('active')
  }
  
  document.querySelectorAll("[data-dropdown].active").forEach(dropdown => {
    if (dropdown === currentDropdown) return
    dropdown.classList.remove("active")
  })
})
```

which is working well, as mouse hover opens the dropdown and keeps that open. But there are two missing functions.

1. When I click somewhere else, dropdown does not close.
2. When I click on the dropdown menu, go to an URL address.
   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've made a directive to address this similar problem and I'm using Bootstrap. But in my case, instead of waiting for the click event outside the element to close the current opened dropdown menu I think it is better if we watch over the 'mouseleave' event to automatically close the menu.

Here's my solution:

**Directive**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {

  @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;

  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') closeDropdown() {
    this.isOpen = false;
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown" appDropdown>
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Test <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/test1">Test1</a></li>
          <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/test2/">Test2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (click) event on the document and check if the event target is not within the dropdown container. If it's not, then you can close the dropdown. Here's an example:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div #container>
      <button (click)="toggleDropdown()">Toggle Dropdown</button>
      <div *ngIf="isDropdownOpen">
        Dropdown Content
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { static: true }) container: ElementRef;
  isDropdownOpen = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      if (!this.container.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
        this.isDropdownOpen = false;
      }
    });
  }

  toggleDropdown() {
    this.isDropdownOpen = !this.isDropdownOpen;
  }
}
```