# Angular : Detect click event inside a div with ngFor inside

Tags: javascript, dom, typescript, angular

I'm working on an Application with a lot of dropdowns, I would like to be able to close the dropdown whenever a click happens outside of this one.

I found some good solutions, but none of them handle the case of having a ngFor in it, when I log the click event target in the ngFor, I get the element but this one doesn't have any parent. I can not detect it with 'find' or 'contains' neither.

Does someone have a solution to detect if this target is part of the dropdown ?

the directive

```
import {
Directive,
ElementRef,
EventEmitter,
Input,
OnInit,
Output,
SimpleChange
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[clickOutside]'})
export class ClickOutside implements OnInit {
@Output() clickOutside:EventEmitter<Event> = new EventEmitter<Event>();

constructor(private _el:ElementRef) {
    this.onClickBody = this.onClickBody.bind(this);
}

ngOnInit() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.onClickBody);
}

private onClickBody(e:Event) {
    if (!this.isClickInElement(e)) {
        this.clickOutside.emit(e);
    }
}

private isClickInElement(e:any):boolean {
    var current = e.target;
    do {
        console.log(current);
        if ( current === this._el.nativeElement ) {
            return( true );
        }
        current = current.parentNode;
    } while ( current );
    return false;
}
}
```

Example of where I call the directive

```
   <div (clickOutside)="onClickedOutside($event)">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let item of itemsList" (click)="selectItem(item)">
                  <span class="item">
                    {{item.name}}
                  </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

When I click on item.name, console.log(current); returns me two lines

```
<span>Item</span>


<li>
  <span>Item</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you also post some of your code?

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. There is no virtual DOM in Angular2.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not able to tell if the click happened in this._el.nativeElement or not. Contains(), find(), and parentNode don't work when you click on an item of ngFor.

Comment: My question is totally off topic, I was splicing my data, and wouldnt think that it would affect the click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Directive({selector: '[clickOutside]'})
export class ClickOutside implements OnInit {
  @Output() clickOutside:EventEmitter<Event> = new EventEmitter<Event>();

  constructor(private _eref: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('window:click')
  private onClickBody(e:Event) {
    if (!this.isClickInElement(e)) {
        this.clickOutside.emit(e);
    }
  }

  private isClickInElement(e:any):boolean {
    return this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target);
  }
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35713421/217408

Comment: No, sorry but it doesnt work in my case, contains() doesnt detect everything i click in my ngFor

Comment: I don't see an `ngFor` in your question.

Comment: Does this mean you could make it work with `contains()`?

Comment: I'm sorry, i was splicing the item after being clicked, I didn't think that the event Object was retro-active, so the element was out of the DOM. Thank you very much for your time, and sorry again

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution works with Chrome but unfortunately not with IE. I'm still looking for another way to do it

```
 private isClickInElement(e:any):boolean {
    var current = e.target;
    if(current == this._el.nativeElement) {
        return true;
    }
    for(let parentKey in e.path) {
        if(e.path[parentKey] == this._el.nativeElement) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: How is this related to virtual DOM or `*ngFor`? What IE version? What does "works not with IE" mean exactly?

Comment: for the virtual DOM i wasnt sure, thats why i put a question mark but thank you for the information. IE11, it seems that event.path is not available is every browsers.

Comment: What about `contains()`? I don't see anything special that would prevent `contains()` to do what you want.

Comment: It returns me false whenever I click on element of ngFor

Comment: A Plunker would be helpful to investigate. I can't imagine `*ngFor` having such an effect. [Plunker template](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html)