# Angular 2 Dart: How to detect click on everything but element?

Tags: angular, events, dart, angular-dart, angular2-dart

On an app with a lot of different components within one component I have a custom Auto-suggest box. The box should be closed if the user clicks anywhere but on the Auto-suggest box (or containing elements of the auto-suggest box).

This is what I would do in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','body',function(e) {
if(e.target!='.suggestbox' && $(e.target).parent('.suggestbox').length <1 ) {
$('.suggestbox').remove();
}
});
```

However In my Angular Dart templates I have:

index.html:

```
<body>
<my-app>
// sub component
// sub sub component
</my-app>
</body>
```

I can think of a possibility in detecting a click on the topmost wrapper within the my-app component and send the action to the subcomponent but this is still not a body click.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
<button (click)="show = true">show dropdown</button>
<div #suggestbox *ngIf="show">...</div>
```

```dart
class AutoSuggestComponent {
  bool show = false;

  @ViewChild('suggestbox') ElementRef suggestbox;

  @HostListener('document:click', [r'$event'])
  onDocumentClick(MouseEvent e) {
    if((suggestbox.nativeElement as HtmlElement).contains(e.target)) {
      // inside the dropdown
    } else {
      // outside the dropdown
    }
  }      
}
```

not tested and the button and div element are only a rough approximation of what the component would look like.

See also [How can I close a dropdown on click outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712379/angular2-close-dropdown-on-click-outside-is-there-an-easiest-way)

**update**

Angular 5 doesn't support global event handlers like `document:...`

Use instead the imperative variant

```dart
class AutoSuggestComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  bool show = false;

  @ViewChild('suggestbox') ElementRef suggestbox;

  StreamSubscription _docClickSub;

  @override
  void ngAfterViewInit() {
    _docClickSub = document.onClick.listen((e) {
      if((suggestbox.nativeElement as HtmlElement).contains(e.target)) {
        // inside the dropdown
      } else {
        // outside the dropdown
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void onDestroy() {
    _docClickSub?.cancel();
  }
}
```