# Hide Menu once clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

How to close the menu dropdown once clicked using typescript. I am able to do using jQuery but I am working on angular 2. I would like to it in typescript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35713421/4248328

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Close dropdown on click outside, is there an easiest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712379/angular2-close-dropdown-on-click-outside-is-there-an-easiest-way)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
<div (click)='clicked = !clicked'>
  <menu [hidden]='clicked'>
  .......
  </menu>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on ionic 2 then following are the steps to hide menu...

First import Menucontroller from `import {MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';`

In your component constructor include menuController like this : `constructor(app: IonicApp, platform: Platform, menu: MenuController)`

Then wherever you wish to close menu do this :  `this.menu.close();`

If you are not using ionic 2 then tell me if u using any plugin in angular for menu? then i can help u with the solution.

Hope this helps..