# Check for multiple events to execute a command in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to change value of a Boolean variable in Angular when a user clicks out of a `div` box. For this I think I should bind the variable with `(mouseleave)` and `(click)` i.e if both the events occur than only value changes. Here Boolean variable is `isOpen` in `.component.html` my code is like this.

```
<div id="box1">

<!--div content-->

</div>
```

In `div` `box1` I want to close it if we click out of it.How can I do this? 

 Below is the TypeScript code for it.

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'service-box',
    templateUrl: './service-box.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./service-box.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceBoxComponent implements OnInit {
    public isOpen = false;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Comment: It's only html, where is javascript?

Comment: I have added the TypeScript code for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I close a dropdown on click outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712379/how-can-i-close-a-dropdown-on-click-outside)

Answer (score -1):

it fairly easy for your html add a directive call ng-click

`<div id="box1" ng-click="yourFunction()">
    </div>`

and in your js

```
$scope.yourFunction(){
mouseleave = true;
}
```

same thing with the directive ng-mouseleave
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I am working with Angular not AngularJs.