# How to use ElementRef to close dropdown on outside click angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dropdown

I've referred to [this other walk through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712379/how-can-i-close-a-dropdown-on-click-outside) and am not able to understand exactly how it works.  I've added this into my ts file:

```
@Component({
  host: {
   '(document:click)': 'onOutsideClick($event)',
  },
})

class SomeComponent() {
  constructor(private _eref: ElementRef) { }

  onOutsideClick(event) {
    console.log('click')
    if(!this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target)){
      this.companyResults = null;
  }
}
```

And want to apply it to this dropdown in HTML where someone will have the ul data set to null when clicked outside.

```
<input id="positionCompanyName" name="companyName_{{i}}" class="search-input"
     [(ngModel)]="candidate.positions[i].company_name"
     (keyup)="$event.target.value && searchCompany$.next($event.target.value)">
       <ul class="search-dropdown-ul" *ngIf="companyResults && positionIndex === i">
         <a class="search-dropdown-div" *ngFor="let companyResult of companyResults" (click)="addCompany(companyResult, i)">             
          <li class="search-dropdown-li">
            {{ companyResult.name } 
           </li>
          </a>
        </ul>
```

Comment: What is the issue? You don't understand what it does or it doesn't work?

Comment: After reading the docs, I am not sure how it works. I'd like to bind it to the search-dropdown-ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElementRef (in the constructor) gives you a reference to the native element (DOM element) of the component itself.

```
  if(!this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target)){
  }
```

This part checks if you clicked on any part of the component, and this isn't something you want. You can check if you clicked on search-dropdown-ul by using a [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)
So, in the HTML, you declare that something is a ViewChild

```
<ul #list class="search-dropdown-ul" *ngIf="companyResults && positionIndex === i">
```

Note the #list. 
Now in the component, you reference it by saying

```
 @ViewChild('list') list: ElementRef;
```

And finally, you see if it's clicked:

```
if(!this.list.nativeElement.contains(event.target)){
  //do your thing here
}
```

Comment: It works! But I am getting a console error saying cannot read nativeElement of undefined. Do I have to call #list somewhere else?

Comment: are you available to check?

Comment: @ViewChild is a decorator, meaning Angular will wrap you typescript class with another class that knows how 'wire' that view child. The error you are getting is because of 
 *ngIf="companyResults && positionIndex === i"

ngIf will add elements to DOM when condition is true, and remove them otherwise. The element #list is destroyed, and you check if it's clicked on it, and that element doesn't exist.

To handle this, you add https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef to the constructor and after the conditions are set to show the #list, call detectChanges() from changeDetectorRef.