# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, viewchild

I've tried the first two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712379/how-can-i-close-a-dropdown-on-click-outside) in this thread as well as trying `ngAfterViewInit()` with a delay and still getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined. This code works as I want it to, but I am still getting console errors.

```
@ViewChild('companyDropdown') companyDropdown: ElementRef;

onOutsideClick(event:any) {
if(!this.companyDropdown.nativeElement.contains(event.target)){
  this.companyResults = null;
 }
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
console.log("afterinit");
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(this.companyDropdown.nativeElement.innerText);
  }, 5000);
}
```

In my constructor:

```
document.addEventListener('click', this.onOutsideClick.bind(this));
```

HTML:

```
<ul #companyDropdown class="search-dropdown-ul" *ngIf="companyResults && positionIndex === i">
 <li class="search-dropdown-li">{{ companyResult.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the element will only ever exist if the condition is true. So most likely the condition is not yet evaluated as true when you are running your .nativeElement. This can be examined by not having an *ngIf in your UL elemnet.

Comment: Wow that is the answer! I've moved the # to the input line above my UL element and no errors. Thank you!!