# hide notification when click on the other place of page in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a modal for show notification in angular 9 .

i have a button for show or hide modal and it's worked find , but i need when click on the other place of page ( not show/hide button )  If the modal is on show, hide it .

this is [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3b4o3?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftopeheader%2Ftopeheader.component.ts) .

html :

```
    <div class="header">
 <button (click)="toggleFunction()">show</button>
<div class="showButton" id="showNotification">
  <span>this is test</span>
</div>
</div>
```

ts :

```
   export class TopeheaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
    toggleFunction() {
        let element = document.getElementById('showNotification');
        if (element.style.display === '' || element.style.display === 'none') {
            element.style.display = 'block';
        } else if (element.style.display === 'block') {
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

**how can i solve this problem ?**

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712379/how-can-i-close-a-dropdown-on-click-outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `HostListener` to detect click outside the target element

component

```js
  isHide: boolean = true;

  toggleFunction(e: MouseEvent) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.isHide = !this.isHide; // toggle the notification 
  }

  @HostListener("document:click") hideOnClick() {
    this.isHide = true;
  }
```

template

```html
<div class="header">
    <button (click)="toggleFunction($event)">show</button>
    <div class="showButton" [ngClass]="{'d-none':isHide}">
        <span>this is test</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

> I just update the logic of update the the element base of toggle class with ngClass directive is more readable an easier.
>   `stopPropagation` stop the event from bubbling so upper event listener will not  capture this event.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jaqfme)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HostListener` and `ViewChild`. Please add this selector on your html

```
<button #showButton (click)="toggleFunction()">show</button>
```

and add your ts file

```
@ViewChild('showButton') showButton: ElementRef;
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    let element = document.getElementById('showNotification');
    if (element.style.display === 'block') {
      if (!document.getElementById('showNotification').contains(event.target) &&
      !this.showButton.nativeElement.contains(event.target) ) {
        element.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
}
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xaqnym)

Comment: This does work, but I would also discourage Angular newcomers from manually manipulating the DOM like this. There are more "Angular" ways of showing and hiding elements.